# Knockout Drag and Drop table

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a table made with `Knockout` and I want to implement drag'n'drop interface for arranging items in the table. Basically, I have a div where I generate new items, which I can drop into the table. Also, items already in the table have to be draggable.

I have been looking into existing solutions, and one of the best ones was [rniemeyer's](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable), but he uses jQueryUI's `sortable` widget.

The reason why this won't work for me is that it **inserts** new elements in an array at a given place, but I need it to override them.

So, I started writing my own custom binding, but I've hit another wall. When I drop the generated item into the table, I create a new element, add the classes, attributes of the dragged item, and append it to the `td`, but the knockout binding for that element is not done...

Code:

```
    var dragData = {};

    ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var dragElement = $(element);
            var dragOptions = {
                revert: true,
                revertDuration: 0,
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    dragData = value.data;
                }
            };

            dragElement.draggable(dragOptions).disableSelection();
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.droppable = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var dropElement = $(element);
            var dropOptions = {
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var div = $('<div/>', {
                        'data-bind': "draggable: " +
                            "{ " +
                                "revert: true," +
                                "revertDuration: 0," +
                                "opacity: 0.75," +
                                "data: " +
                                    "{" +
                                        "selectedSubject: " + dragData.selectedSubject + "," +
                                        "selectedTeacher: " + dragData.selectedTeacher + "," +
                                        "numberOfClasses: 1" +
                                    "}" +
                            "}"
                    }).addClass('schedule-item panel-info');

                    $(div).append('<div class="row">' + dragData.selectedSubject + '</div>');
                    $(div).append('<div class="row">' + dragData.selectedTeacher + '</div>');

                    dropElement.html(div);
                }
            };

            if (value.accept)
                ko.utils.extend(dropOptions, { accept: value.accept });

            if (value.hoverClass)
                ko.utils.extend(dropOptions, { hoverClass: value.hoverClass });

            if (value.tolerance)
                ko.utils.extend(dropOptions, { tolerance: value.tolerance });

            dropElement.droppable(dropOptions);
        }
```

`ko.applyBindings()` returns this error: `You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.`

Because the data binding isn't done, the item in the table remains undraggable.

Is there a way to accomplish the data binding? Or is there a way to implement the "override" mechanism into the `jQuery UI sortable` widget?

Comment: Have you considered using the jquery sortable plugin's update event to observe the position the item was dropped and simply splice out the item that directly follows that position?  That would effectively "overwrite" the item in that position AFTER the drop has finished.  The only downside is your array will increase in length for a moment before the event fires and you delete the item in position+1.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is really unintuitive, I have a feeling the users will have problems with it. The solution, it seems, will have to be without the `sortable` widget.

Comment: I don't see this code calling `ko.applyBindings` at all .. anyway, consider using `ko.applyBindingToNode(theCreatedDiv, theBindings)` instead of building up the data-bind attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you should try [KO Template bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), look at section 2 for foreach bindings.  The templating will render each new dropped object according to the pattern you specify and new bindings will be automaticall added for the new elements.

It looks like you're circumventing ko and inserting the new elements directly into the DOM, and knockout doesn't add the new bindings in that case.